# Converting a datename(dw script from sqlserver to sqlite

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlite

I've got a sqlserver query that will get the day of week for a DateTime query but I've got to convert it to sqlite.  Below is a snippet of the query from Sql Server :

```
datename(dw,tblSomeTable.Eventdate),
```

What is need is the sqlite equivalent for "datename(dw,tblSomeTable.deventdate)".  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the way I changed the query was returning int's but I wanted something that would return days of the week so I replaced datename(dw,tblSomeTable.deventdate) with :

```
case cast (strftime('%w', tblSomeTable.EventDate) as integer)
  when 0 then 'Sunday'
  when 1 then 'Monday'
  when 2 then 'Tuesday'
  when 3 then 'Wednesday'
  when 4 then 'Thursday'
  when 5 then 'Friday'
  else 'Saturday' end as servdayofweek
```

And it got me exactly what I needed.